# msbuild works whereas dotnet build fails

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, msbuild

I have some libraries built on C# .NET Core 3.1.

When I execute the command

```
dotnet build  "core\core.csproj"
```

I get the following error

> C:\Users\christos.nuget\packages\visual-stylecop.msbuild\4.7.59\build\Visual-StyleCop.MSBuild.Targets(107,5): error MSB4062: The "StyleCopTask" task could not be loaded from the
> assembly
> C:\Users\christos.nuget\packages\visual-stylecop.msbuild\4.7.59\build..\tools\StyleCop.dll.
> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
> The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the
>  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its
> dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class
> that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

But when I use msbuild

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe'  "core\core.csproj"
```

it finishes without problems.

Any idea why?

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: https://improveandrepeat.com/2021/03/stylecop-for-net-5-projects-installation/

Comment: Or upgrade to .NET 5, use the SDK `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` and set `UseWindowsForms` ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props-desktop)) - `System.Windows.Forms.dll` is not available on your platform